# How do I set a PHP variable to an array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, swiftmailer

I am using Swift Mailer for PHP and there are times where there are multiple email addresses to send to.  Having inherited a database that has several email addresses per one cell only split by comma's it is not feasible for this to change this to correct standards.

When I use the following in the sendTo field in Swift Mailer, it works just fine.

```
$email = array('name@email.com', 'name@email.com', 'name@email.com'); // Works
```

However the email addresses in the database are in the form of

```
name@email.com,name@email.com,name@email.com
```

What I tried is the following.

```
$dbemails = "name@email.com,name@email.com,name@email.com"; // Fetched
$dbemailsrp = str_replace(",", "', '", $dbemails); // Replace , with ', '
$dbemailscp = "'".$dbemailsrp."'"; // Add front and back '
$email = array($dbemailscp); // Doesn't work
```

Then I tried to put the $email in swift mailer it does not work after going through this process, but works if I manually set up the array as shown in the first block of code.

Any ideas why building the array this way does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not create an array, it creates an array with a single item as a string. You need to split up the email addresses into an array, you can do this using the `explode` function, ie:

```
$emails = explode(",", "name@email.com,name@email.com,name@email.com");
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it!  As soon as the time limit is done, I will mark yours best answer.

Comment: You're welcome. A little bit of advice, become familiar with the two functions `print_r` and `var_dump`, they are invaluable when learning PHP and debugging.

Comment: Excellent idea! I have learned quite a bit over the years but still learning. Mistakes teach us a lot and I am sure this is as useful as turning errors on!